# Mysql search query with options

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form where users can insert their skills into a mysql database.
They can select one from three options: *painting, drawing or painting & drawing*. One of these values is then inserted into a field in the database.

I want to be able to query these values using a form with selects. I've got it working fine but have run into a problem possibly with the logic.

If someone selects *painting* from the search form this should return all rows where both *painting* and *painting & drawing* are the values but in my form it only returns values that equal *painting*.

Likewise if someone selects *painting & drawing* from the search form only rows are returned where that exact value exists but really this should return all rows where both *painting* and *drawing* exist. How can I achieve this?
A piece of the search code is below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="job"></label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <select id="jobtitle" name="jobtitle" class="form-control">
                              <option value="" disabled selected>jobtitle</option>
                  <option value="drawing">
                    Drawing
                  </option>
                  <option value="painting">
                    Painting
                  </option>
   <option value="Drawing & Painting">Drawing & Painting</option>

                </select>
```

The mysql query is:

```
sql="select name, jobtitle from mytable where jobtitle='jobtitle'"
```

Comment: you could change <option value="Drawing & Painting">Drawing & Painting</option> to <option value="drawing,painting">Drawing & Painting</option> and then use mysql find_in_set on the jobtitle field in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like instead. You could get away with

```
SELECT name,jobtitle FROM mytable WHERE jobtitle LIKE "%painting%";
```

and it will select everything where "painting" is in the field. % is a wildcard. You'll have to rewrite it slightly with PHP string concatenation to include the variable, but this should give you a good start, right?

This will work for you if you put more options in and have (Painting, Drawing & Coloring) or (coloring, painting & drawing). It will return a match for either because 'painting' is in both fields.

Comment: that wont work if he is passing "painting & drawing" as the value to search for.

Comment: ah yes, because of the & sign.

Comment: So I've followed FuncDoc's suggestion. Can anyone tell me why this does not work? `code` SELECT name from  mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('jobtitle', 'painting,drawing') `code`

Comment: why are you adding the find_in_set bit?

Comment: Because I'm trying to find all rows where 'painting,drawing' exist if I search for either painting or drawing.

Comment: In the end I've decided to use Tyler's suggestion "Where jobtitle LIKE %painting%". It's working how I want it to. Thanks.

Comment: Also take out the & sign though when you add both titles in, otherwise that will mess you up